# Why are the p-values for a binomial test very different from the p-values for a chi-squared test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I am testing if a coin is fair by throwing it `n`-times and having `n/2 + sqrt(n)` heads.

However, I get *very different* p-values from both binomial and chi-squared tests. In particular the relative difference `(chis_p - bin_p)/chis_p` is close to 50% even when `n` grows larger and larger.

I already read the post [Does a 2*2 chi-square test give the same results as a binomial test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420944/does-a-22-chi-square-test-give-the-same-results-as-a-binomial-test) that says that the differences may be due to the implementation. But I think 50% of the difference is far too big and so would like to know if there is something else going on.

The following is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import binom
from scipy.stats import chi2

def binomial_test_p_value(tosses, heads):
    # Probability of heads for a fair coin
    p_head = 0.5

    # Calculate p-value using the binomial test
    # The alternative='greater' indicates we are looking at the probability of getting at least 'heads' number of heads
    p_value = binom.sf(heads - 1, tosses, p_head)

    return p_value

def chi_squared_test_p_value(tosses, heads):
    # Calculate tails
    tails = tosses - heads

    # Expected frequency of heads and tails for a fair coin
    expected = tosses / 2

    # Calculate chi-squared statistic
    chi_squared_stat = ((heads - expected)**2 / expected) + ((tails - expected)**2 / expected)

    # Calculate p-value using the chi-squared test with 1 degree of freedom
    p_value = chi2.sf(chi_squared_stat, 1)

    return p_value

bin_p_list = []
chis_p_list = []
diff_list = []
relative_diff_list = []
step = 100
for tosses in range(step, step*1000, step):
    head_diff = int(tosses**0.5)
    heads = tosses/2 + head_diff
    bin_p = binomial_test_p_value(tosses, heads)
    chis_p = chi_squared_test_p_value(tosses, heads)
    diff_p = chis_p - bin_p
    relative_diff = 100*diff_p/chis_p
    bin_p_list.append(bin_p)
    chis_p_list.append(chis_p)
    diff_list.append(diff_p)
    relative_diff_list.append(relative_diff)

plt.plot(bin_p_list, label='Binomial p-value')
plt.plot(chis_p_list, label='Chi-squared p-value')
plt.title('P-values for binomial and chi-squared tests for n/2 + sqrt(n) heads on n coin throws')
plt.xlabel('Number of coin throws')
plt.ylabel('p-value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(relative_diff_list)
plt.title('Relative difference (chis_p - bin_p)/chis_p in p-values')
plt.xlabel('Number of coin throws')
plt.ylabel('Relative difference [%]')
plt.show()
```

I also include the plots that you can produce with the code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your binomial test is one-tailed (rejects only for large numbers of heads) and your chi-squared test is two-tailed (rejects for large or small numbers of heads).  So the chisquared test should have twice the rejection rate in larger samples.